# React router can't pass params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I m using react router for my project but I can't figure out why I can't pass a parameter into my Url.

Here I defined my routes :

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <Route path="home" >
                  <Route path="editor/:id" component={EditorContainer}/>
              </Route>
          </Route>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In my component I have this line:

```
<Link to="/home/editor/:id" params={{id: elem.id}}
                                                 onClick = {onOpen}>{elem.title} </Link>
```

To open my element in the EditorContainer

It open it correctly in my EditorContainer but the url is like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/home/editor/:id
```

and not like for example :

```
http://localhost:8080/home/editor/1234
```

Can you tell me what I m doing wrong please ?

Comment: Change your component to 
`<Link to="/home/editor/1234" />`, is this help?

Comment: No because, the id depends of the element where I click

Comment: I meant something like this
`var link='/home/editor" + elem.id' <Link to={link} />`

Comment: oh yes thats working thanks ! but it's strange that the other code not working

Comment: If you can mark my answer and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your component to:

```
var link='/home/editor' + elem.id;
<Link to={link} />
```

You can check [React-Router Link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1fb4f7abb9a7f32a82fb3bc15ace7012fead7885/modules/Link.js) to get more info about `Link` component

This should help